# How can I access python3.6+ from Haskell?

Tags: haskell

[haskell-cpython](https://john-millikin.com/software/haskell-cpython) works up to python3.4, but it is a too old version of python. The library also seems not to be maintained anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to download a more recent version at this [fork](https://github.com/ekalosak/haskell-cpython/commit/829da05dc5117b2f1d15fdcbd9796b1a65f53c3d) changing *package.yaml*

```
dependencies:
- cpython
```

and also *stack.yaml*

```
extra-deps:
- github: ekalosak/haskell-cpython
  commit: 829da05dc5117b2f1d15fdcbd9796b1a65f53c3d
```